# Always display navigation bar on screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

So I have the navigation bar always on the screen when scrolling down past the header image. However, what I am trying to get is that whenever you load the webpage you can always see the navigation bar. Right now you have to scroll down to see the navigation bar which is not the desired appearance for me. Here is the desired effect I am going for http://www.webdingo.net/zoo/ and here is a link to the site currently www.blank.com. Also I am using bootstrap, finally here is some relevant code.

HTML for header/navigation

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</header>

<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Other</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

css for header

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
height: 100%;
}

.fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
margin: 50px 0;
}


#nav.affix{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alter the javascript in order to get an animation, but you can try this: (Just try to scroll within the carousel.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/epyuepjv/1/)

Here's the code:

```
var mousewheelevt1 = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" ;

$('.carousel-inner').bind(mousewheelevt1, function(e){

        var evt = window.event || e ;
        evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
        var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta;

     if(delta < 0)
        {
            var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    nav.style.position = 'fixed';
    nav.style.top = '0px';


        }

});
```

I've changed the css a little bit, and the html, too. You will find it in the fiddle.

**Please note: This is not the complete desired result, but it will show you the direction.**

Comment: Thanks for the help here. This sparked an idea for me to get what I wanted :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the following CSS to whatever div(s) you want to stick:

```
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;      //Which of these you use depends on where you want the menu to stick----   This sticks to the top
      left: 0;      //This sticks to the left
      right: 0;     //This sticks to the right
      bottom: 0;     //This sticks to the bottom
```